# How to check output of a created URL?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a RuneScape(an MMORPG Game) Name Checker. For this i am using an IRC bot. The URL i am using to check names is this- http://rscript.org/lookup.php?type=namecheck&name=

I am using javascript to take input and go to this url for checking names. The code i am using is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nameCheck()
{
var username = document.getElementById('uname').value;
var url = "http://rscript.org/lookup.php?type=namecheck&name=";
var curl = url + username;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="textBox" id="uname" type="text" maxlength="15" required/>
<input type="button" onclick="nameCheck()" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

To proceed with this i need a code that could check the output of the final url created ie. 
`curl`. If the output page looks like this:

```
START
NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE
SUGGESTIONS: blah blah blah
END
```

Then the code should run the function `nameNotAva()`. And if the output is like this:

```
START
NAMECHECK: AVALIBLE
END
```

Then the code should run the function `nameAva()`.

**The question**:

I just want that using javascript the output be evalutaled to check that if `NAMECHECK: NOTAVAILABLE` is a part of the output page or not. If yes then a function `nameNotAva()` should be run. Otherwise a function `nameAva()` should be run.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'd say: make a JQuery AJAX call with the url. The output will be returned as a string. Run a regex or a strpos for "namecheck: notavailble" or something.

Comment: I just want that using javascript the output be evalutaled to check that if `NAMECHECK: NOTAVAILABLE` is a part of the output page or not. If yes then a function `nameNotAva()` should be run. Otherwise a function `nameAva()` should be run.

Comment: @sdnr1: don't forget to escape the name: `curl = url+encodeURI(username)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know what language u are using, with jQuery u can do following things

1. You can load the response inside a div.

   ```
   function nameCheck()
   {

   var username = document.getElementById('uname').value;

   var url = "http://rscript.org/lookup.php?type=namecheck&name=";

   var curl = url + username;

   var output = $('#someDiv').load( curl ).html() // .html() will give you the output or what the page 

    if( output.contains('NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE'){ nameNotAva(); }

   }
   ```
2. You can use simple AJAX and get the response text ( may be with async false)

   ```
   function nameCheck()
   {

   var username = document.getElementById('uname').value;

   var url = "http://rscript.org/lookup.php?type=namecheck&name=";

   var curl = url + username;
    $.ajax({
        url : curl,
        type : 'GET' //or 'POST',
        success : function( urlOutput ){ 
                if( urlOutput .contains('NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE'){ 
                     nameNotAva(); 
                  } 
             }
      });
   }
   ```

Comment: I dont want the user to see the output of the page. I just want that using javascript the output be evalutaled to check that if `NAMECHECK: NOTAVAILABLE` is a part of the output page or not. If yes then a function `nameNotAva()` should be run. Otherwise a function `nameAva()` should be run.

Comment: Man.. Come on!!! You can always remove the print statement!. You want the output i got it to you. You asign the ouput to a string ,and do some string manipulation.. Phew!! Wait editing the answer