# Code is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nameNotAva()
{
alert("Name already exists.");
//some code
}

function nameCheck() 
{
var username = document.getElementById('uname').value;
var url = "http://rscript.org/lookup.php?type=namecheck&name=";
var curl = url + username;
 $.ajax({
     url : curl,
     type : 'GET',
     success : function(urlOutput){ 
             if(urlOutput.contains('NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE')){ 
                  nameNotAva(); 
               } 
          }
   });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="textBox" id="uname" type="text" maxlength="15" required/>
<input type="button" onclick="nameCheck()" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is there in the `$.ajax` part. I know this because when i put `alert(curl);` just before the ajax part, it displays the correct URL. If you want the complete info that what i am trying to do then goto- [How to check output of a created URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982906/how-to-check-output-of-a-created-url)

I am using jquery library of the latest version.

Comment: `String.prototype.contains` isn’t a thing in JavaScript; that could be it. `if(urlOutput.indexOf('NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE') !== -1)`. Also, have you included jQuery?

Comment: What "exactly" is the problem. You've only specified that there "is" a problem. If you want to check what's happening then use: FireBug, Chrome Developer ToolBar or IE Developer ToolBar. They are all accessible by pressing F12 - apart from FireBug which you will need to download and install into FireFox first

Comment: Maybe you should include your `jQuery` library. It could help a bit.

Comment: Is your success function being hit?

Comment: i have included it(obviously)!

Comment: This is the library i am using- `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />`

Comment: @sdnr1 — No, not obviously, you provided a what appeared to be a complete HTML document. It isn't usual to expect bits of code required to reproduce your problem to be missing from that.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't included the jQuery library so `$` is undefined and the script will error on the Ajax part.

In general, if you have a problem with some JavaScript: Open the JS console in your browser and pay attention to any error messages.

*Update after comments suggest that the code in the question was incomplete*:

> This is the library i am using- `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />`

Script elements are not defined as empty. The end tag is required.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but I was hoping it wasn't that simple!

Comment: @sdnr1 — Do you mean that "`<script />` is "properly"? (it isn't) or that you, again, provided code that wasn't the code you were actually using?

Comment: i have used `</script>`. What you are talking about is a typing mistake that i make in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

### http://jsfiddle.net/ksJEj/

Change the input type:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>`

include this in your `<head></head>` tags:

### HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this too:

### HTML/JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function{
    function nameNotAva() {
        alert("Name already exists.");
        //some code
    }

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $('#uname').val();
        $.get("http://rscript.org/lookup.php", {
            'type': 'namecheck',
            'name': username
        }, function (urlOutput) {
            if ($(urlOutput).contains('NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE') == true) nameNotAva();
                else alert("woohoo");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @sdnr1 You are trying to grab html data from another website from an AJAX query. The error is caused by an  `access-control-cross-origin` issue. The only ways to fix this would be either to receive json data or to allow the specific server to send you html data.

This code works. The fact that you can't fix your server is not my problem. You are welcome.

Comment: I am very thankful that you are helping. But i can't understand why the code is not working for me. It is also not working on jsfiddle link you gave i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/ksJEj/. Also i have found a java application that does a similar that i am trying to do. This is the source- http://www.crazyandcoding.com/downloads/source/namecheckersrc.rar ,but i don't know how it works cus i don't know java